# "Additional Module Dependencies" and "Additional BMI Directories" settings in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, module, c++20

Let's say I have two modules - Module1, Module2.
Each module has its own project in Visual Studio.
How to import Module2 into Module1 using the "Additional Module Dependencies" or "Additional BMI Directories" settings?

Issue: Visual Studio (2019/2022) cannot find any symbols from Module2.

Adding a reference to Module2 into Module1 does not help.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/a-tour-of-cpp-modules-in-visual-studio/ doesn't help much

Comment: I suggest that you could submit this question on [Microsoft Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html). You could put forward your needs there.

Comment: Did you get this to work? Could you share your fix?

Comment: No :(//////////

Comment: Absolutely fabulous. And here we are, more than a year later, and no mortal knows how to use this.

Comment: I thought that just adding the other project as reference should fix the issue. Module Directories and Module Dependencies are for 3rd party modules.

Comment: Setting the other project as a reference works for me at least. But I'm still trying to reference a module from another VS solution.

Comment: Oh and I almost forgot to try to answer your question: maybe you don't have the "All Modules Are Public" set to "Yes". This may prevent detection of the modules from outside of the project.

Answer (score 4):

Projects with modules can only be included when they have a configuration type equal to static library (lib). For other types such as dynamic library and executable you will need to set the Additional Module Dependencies. When a project compiles as a static library, the including project only needs to add a reference to your module project. When referencing a non lib project you will need to compile the module manually since the Build dependencies do not seem to handle this for you.

Comment: This may not be accurate. I can't get VS2022 to compile a project referring to a static lib project with modules without adding module dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Additional Module Dependencies" to point to the ifc you want to import symbols from (e.g. StaticLib1.ixx.ifc)

This is what the compiler expects:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/module-reference?view=msvc-160

Comment: This does not work (for me). Whatever I feed the Additional Header Dependencies, the linker refuses to resolve the external symbols. Setting the "Scan Sources for Module Dependencies" seems to aid VS in some code completion, but that's about it.

Comment: @HJLebbink why you feed Additional *Header* Dependencies when you were ought to add filenames to Additional *Module* Dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

If everything seems correct but it does not work - check that you don't import the module in the precompiled header or vice versa.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29952731)